# Wildcard to select all items in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm currently using Local Solr for doing geo searching.  It takes in lat and long parameters as well as a search query.  I want to create nearby functionality, where I don't need to provide a location and not a search query.  Is there a way to provide a wildcard query that matches all elements then order by the distance?  Is the best to create another field and place the same value in all fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the query `*:*` to match all values in all fields.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_delete_all_documents_from_my_index.3F for an example on how to query all documents using the `*:*` wildcard.

See also http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax for general Solr syntax help.

Comment: hi Aaron, could you point me to some documentation?  thanks for your help.

Comment: Example for matching any `id` using a browser: `http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?q=id:*`

Answer (score 2):

You may use Solr spatial search to sort by distance, and your query can be *:* if you want to pull all documents from your index.

```
   eg: ?q=*:*&sfield=search_field&pt=22.12,-55.56&sort=geodist() asc
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch